# Assign my working XML corrections in HTML/JS to angular js

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, odata, xml-serialization, integration

My backend delivers an XML response with tags that first have to be corrected to be processed further. I make that work by converting it to a string, make the corrections, and convert it back to XML.

I want it to also work in AngularJS, so how do I assign those things in my Module / Controller?

For now, my module and my controller look like this (copied from an other example):

```
<script>var myModule = angular.module("MyModule", ['ODataResources']);
myModule.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $odataresource) {
$scope.results =


        $odataresource("http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products")
                .odata()
                .filter('UnitPrice', '>', 10)
                .filter('Discontinued', true)
                .orderBy('UnitsInStock', 'asc')
                .expand('Category')
                .query();
});</script>
```

My solution is working with HTML/JS when you insert the below code on this page: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_replace

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <style>
 table,th,td {
 border : 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 th,td {
 padding: 5px;
 }
</style>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
  myFunction(xhttp);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET",        "https://xsgeos0015309874trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/s0015309874trial/xsgeo/geotabelle/geoDB/GeotabelleODataService.xsodata/Adressen?$top=2", true);
xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
var i;
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;

var s1 = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc);
var s2 = new String(s1);
var replaced = s2.split('d:Latitude').join('Latitude');
var replaced2 = replaced.split('d:Longitude').join('Longitude');
var replaced3 = replaced2.split('d:Hausnummer').join('Hausnummer');
var replaced4 = replaced3.split('d:PLZ').join('PLZ');
var replaced5 = replaced4.split('d:ortsname').join('ortsname');
var replaced6 = replaced5.split('d:Street').join('Street');
var replaced7 = replaced6.split('m:type').join('type');
var replaced8 = replaced7.split('m:properties').join('properties');
console.log(replaced8);

var result = $.parseXML(replaced8);
alert(result);
var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
var x = result.getElementsByTagName("properties");

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
table += "<tr><td>" +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("Longitude")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td><td>" +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("Latitude")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td></tr>";

}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;


}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a run block as the simplest migration path:

```js
var app = angular.module('foo', []);

function foo()
  {
  function loadDoc() 
    {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
      {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
        {
        myFunction(xhttp);
        }
      };
      
    xhttp.open("GET", "data:application/xml,<root></root>", true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
  
  function myFunction(xml) 
    {
    var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";  
  
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
    }

  loadDoc();
  }

app.run(foo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="foo"></div>
<table id="demo"></table>
```

**References**

- [DefinitelyTyped/angular.d.ts - Type definitions for Angular JS 1.6](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/types/angular/index.d.ts)
- [DefinitelyTyped/angular.d.ts - Type definitions for Angular JS 1.5](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/types/angularjs/angular.d.ts)
- [DefinitelyTyped/angular.d.ts - Type definitions for Angular JS 1.4](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/1.4.1/angularjs/angular.d.ts)
- [GitHub - RyanCavanaugh/dts-dom: A DOM library for generation TypeScript declaration (.d.ts) files](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh/dts-dom)